# Dynamically change height of div in every 1st 2nd & 3rd li according to biggest child image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a long `<ul>` list of images, each contained within a `<div>`. Our li's always have a width of 33.3%, so there are always 3 lis, divs and imgs in a single row.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>Some text...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>Some different text...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>Another text...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>More text...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>Even more text...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>Again some text...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div><img...></div>
        <div>Some text...</div>
    </li>
    etc...   
</ul>
```

Now we need to get the current visible (not natural) height of the biggest image in each row.

We then need to change the height of each containing div in that row to this value.

Then repeat for the next row until the end of our `<ul>` tag.

Javascript/jQuery can do this for sure, but no luck so far :)

EDIT: just realised we forgot some important information: the images have to be vertically centered in each `<div>`. The second set of div's containing our text have to be vertically set to start at the same level.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want all images in the row to be same size as the biggest image in the row. Not sure it's a good idea. whenever smaller images shorter then the biggest image in the row and you will change their height the proportion of those images will be broken and they will not look good

Comment: Can you post your actual code? "we need to get the current visible (not natural) height of the biggest image in each row" - I'm guessing you have CSS that makes the image height visibly different than the natural height? We need to see the code that does that.

Comment: Why not wrap each 3 `li`s in their own `div` or `ul`? This sounds like it could be done using flex boxes.

Comment: Is it something like Google image search?

Comment: The divs already got the same size. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: currently ALL the divs in ALL the lis have a fixed height (height:337px;) but we actually need the div heights in EACH row to adjust dynamically to the highest image in EACH row

Comment: Can you post some runnable code? it will make your intention more clear.